# Failed to call function from external javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to use javascript to check for the `radio button` whether is checked or not.
If the `tidak setuju` radio button is checked or `setuju` radio button is not checked, I want to `alert` a dialog box.
But somehow the `onclick` function at the `submit` button is not working.

I temporarily uploaded my page to a free server.

[Here](http://anonynewbie.site11.com/BorangStaf.html) is my site, and [this](http://anonynewbie.site11.com/js/checkForm.js) is the external javascript file.

What is wrong with my code?

In my HTML, the code for the radio button and the submit button :

```
    <tr>

      <td width = "25%">

          <div align="right">

            <input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" value="Setuju" id="RadioGroup1_0" />

      </div></td>

        <td width = "25%" class = "left">Setuju</td>

        <td width = "25%" class = "right"><div align="right">

          <input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" value="Tidak Setuju" id="RadioGroup1_1" />

      </div></td>

        <td width = "25%" class = "left">Tidak Setuju</td>

    </tr>

</table>

<input id="Submit" name="Submit" type="submit" value="Submit" class="Button" onclick="return agree(); " />
```

And here is the javascript :

```
function agree(){

if(document.getElementById("RadioGroup1_1").checked || !document.getElementById("RadioGroup1_0").checked)
{
    alert("Anda mesti setuju syarat-syarat permohonan.");
    return false;
}
}
```

Correction :

I forget to set `ID` for my other `textfield` where there is more conditions in the function `agree()`. Hence, the function did not run properly.

Here is my error :

```
<input type="text" name="stafNumber" />    <-- missing ID declaration, but declared in javascript.
```

Comment: Not related to your specific question, but the table cells that contain your radio buttons both have id="left". ID's must be unique throughout the document, so this is invalid. You should use  class="left" instead.

Comment: Ok, I'll try to improve it. So, ID should be specific for only one element?

Comment: Please post the relevant code as it is required to understand the question. Other users should be able to benefit from your question too, even if the links are not available any more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On line 19 of checkform.js you have an error in your validation function:

```
var address = document.getElementById("stafAddress").value;
```

This gives "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null" because there is no such element with ID "stafAddress" on your page.

There is also another error that you will need to fix on line 13:

```
document.getElementById("error_stafName").style.display = 'none';
```

Gives a similar error for a similar reason.

Have you tried Chrome's Javascript debugger?  It's very useful for working out what's wrong.  You can open it at Menu > Tools > Developer Tools > Sources.

Comment: Thanks. Seems like I forget to put an ID for the textfield.